# Input fields rendered very differently in different browsers

Tags: html, css, xhtml, cross-browser, textfield

Okay, so I am in the process of designing a website which has a login form at the top-right corner of a webpage. I set the size attribute of its input fields and I am getting some interesting results. Below is a group of screenshots that I threw together. I even stacked them for you all. I am even throwing in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vAwn/) for you all. So four things:

- I aligned them based on the bottom right hand corner of the password input field in the stacked image. Don't ask why.
- I design with borders on everything until the layout is correct, then I remove them and add the colors and images and whatnot.
- The IE 9 screenshot is based on Adobe's BrowserLab since I am working on a Mac.
- Note that the WebKit-based browsers (Safari and Chrome) render the same size.

I could not find anything to reveal what is happening after a series of searches. Maybe it's because  it's hard to word a question like this into simple search terms (or at least for me)…

With all of this said, my question is why is are the input fields rendered so differently, and most importantly, *how* can I remedy this (without JavaScript or the dependence on User Agents preferably)?

[image: Screenshots]

Comment: How could this possibly matter? No one browses your site on all of those browsers simultaneously. Consider whether or not each rendering is *usable*. You've already wasted too much time chasing pixel perfection, all for no justifiable end. Notice that buttons look different on a Mac and a PC. The default styling tends to match the operating system's native controls. I think that's a good thing; what purpose could you possibly have to override it? And what happens to your perfect design when the user increases the font size in their browser?

Comment: @Cody, you can leave remarks like that in your head. I'm not trying to achieve pixel perfection. That would be stupid. I realize that *almost* nobody browses my site on numerous browsers. However, I did not like the FF or Opera renderings. They were too large. It's kind of a big deal when there is a difference as large as that across browsers. What if I had something that was being covered up by the larger renderings? Only comment if you are going to be constructive.

Comment: I think that was extremely constructive. My point is that you're wasting time chasing a pipe dream. There's no way to get pixel perfection. Your whole site will be "too large" when the user increases the font size in their browser. Then what?

Comment: @Cody, "There's no way to get pixel perfection." May I reference you to what I just got finished saying? "I'm not trying to achieve pixel perfection." As for the font-size increase, my mindset is that if they want to change the font-size, let them. The only layout difference it will make is the size of those input fields and length of the page (besides the size of the font obviously).

Comment: @Cody, excuse me for noticing a 66 pixel difference. I think that's something to be concerned about. 10 pixels, maybe even 20 would be fine, but 66?

Comment: @Cody, besides I figured someone with as much experience on stackoverflow as you would know the rules: "Be nice. Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you. We’re all here to learn together. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know. Bring your sense of humor." You ignored that entire paragraph. If it's an argument you're looking for, there are better places for you. If you had this interaction with a newbie to stackoverflow, that would likely steer him/her(/it) away. Also keep in mind that text conversations aren't the same as voice. Watch the wording.

Comment: Yes, I agree that being nice is important. I'll admit that my sense of humour might be best described as "quirky", but I'm not generally a mean-spirited person. As I mentioned before, my original comment was not at all intended to be offensive. I'm still not sure how exactly you read it to interpret it that way. I didn't intend to incite an argument. (Although, while we're sharing, my biggest personality flaw is that I inevitably argue back when people try to argue/disagree with me. I think that happened here. Sorry.) And I honestly don't understand how text conversations differ from voice.

Comment: @Cody, What I meant by text conversations differing from voice conversations is that if you ask I would like a donut, for example, I'll say, "Sure." Hearing my tone of voice says just as much as the words themselves do. However, that cannot easily be shown in text. The tone of the words is up to the reader. That being said, I never found your comments offensive. As I said, I felt they weren't very constuctive: "You've already wasted too much time chasing pixel perfection, all for no justifiable end." This came off as somewhat snobby to me. Just watch the word choice, bro.

Comment: @Cody, Even I stuggle with it sometimes. Almost got fired on two separate occasions due to poor word choice via email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `size` attribute sets the [number of characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-size-INPUT) that the field will display (in the case of `text` and `password` fields).  Different browsers use different default fonts, font sizes, and ppi measures, meaning that you get massively different sized (in pixels) fields.

Also, as the spec says, this is merely the "initial" width of the control, and the browser is free to resize the control if it decides it needs to in the course of reflowing the entire page.

To even have a hope of making this field close to the same (pixel) size on different browsers, you'll have to style it with CSS.  That being said, there is probably a good reason that each of these are different sizes - mostly having to do with default fonts - and if you pixel-restrict the size of the field that means some browsers will display more actual text than others.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that the input tag does not inherit the font-family property. That looks a whole lot better. Thanks. :)