# Strange HTML form field size discrepancy across browsers

Tags: html, css, size, field, textfield

Anyone know why this happens?

```
<input type="text" name="number" size="12" value="(555)555-5555">
<input type="text" name="ext" maxlength="20" size="1">
```

Nothing too interesting in the CSS.[image]

Comment: So you want to know why text inputs are a different widths in different browsers?

Comment: Yes. Are they supposed to be? I mean, the font size looks identical.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Input fields rendered very differently in different browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361606/input-fields-rendered-very-differently-in-different-browsers)

Comment: Thanks, Clive -- didn't see that one.

Answer (score 0):

Look into box-sizing. Different field types render at different box-sizes. Setting them to **box-sizing: border-box;** and defining a width value in your CSS should give you consistent widths.