# Inputs behaving unusually?

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, mobile-safari

I am having alot of trouble putting my problem into words, and it would be much appreciated if someone could perhaps 'sum it up better'. Anyways, I'm styling a form to gather information, as it is targeted at a mobile device, I want the fields to stretch to 100%, filling the screen. Using a text area, this works fine on all mobile OS's, however, by using a standard , the layout on the iPhone is broken, note this does not occur on Android. I believed it was a bug with Safari, but it works in desktop Safari, so maybe something to do with iOS rendering?

[image: Standard expected behaviour, and in browsers]
Standard expected behaviour.

[image: iOS Behaviour]
iOS behaviour

Note:
A live preview of the site can be found at http://www.draganmarjanovic.com
However, this is only present on a resolution of <720px.

The same CSS code is used for both the input and the text area. - Cheers

Comment: `box-sizing:border-box;`

Comment: @MLeFevre That works, but why are the text area and input responding differently?

Comment: I believe it is due to how a browser renders the form tags, each browser renders them slightly different.

Comment: No problem, here is a helpful answer to fill you in a little more about this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361606/input-fields-rendered-very-differently-in-different-browsers

Comment: Your elements are at `width:100%`, but different browsers are also allocating them additional padding by default, if you change each element to have `padding:0px;` it'll probably display fine as well. The box model doesn't take padding into consideration when calculating the whole element width, whereas border-box does. So whatever browser you have problems with, under the box model it'll make the element `width:100%;` _and then_ add the padding the browser gives that element by default. Here's a better article rather than my crappy explanation - http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: @MLeFevre The example on the link you provided is exactly what the OP is displaying. Good job mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding on the `textarea` and the `input` are different by default (user-agent stylesheet) and you haven't given a reset value for them. Try setting `padding:0;` on both of them, it should work.

Why did it work when you tried `box-sizing:border-box;` as @MLeFevre told you, you ask? Because what this property does is make the `padding` count as `width` and not as an addition of it (which is the normal browser behaviour we've had till CSS3). It does the same with `border` width too. So, it didn't matter the default `padding` wasn't zero because the width would be 100% no matter what padding you set.